# Disable timerTrigger for Azure Function after they are deploy from Node ( typescript) for testing purposes

Tags: typescript, azure-functions

I am currently testing a server-less application in Azure. The problem is like this: I need to make a change in a database and then check that the change is sent to an event hub. The problem is that the Azure function is setup with a `timerTrigger` ( every 5 minutes ). So, in my test, I would like to deactivate the `timerTrigger`, So I don't have an unexpected run for the function ( Then in the test, I can run it when I want ).

I am using typescript to code my test. is there an SDK that allow me to do that ?

I know I can do it with powershell:

```
az functionapp config appsettings set --name <myFunctionApp> \
--resource-group <myResourceGroup> \
--settings AzureWebJobs.CheckAssetOnTimerTrigger.Disabled=true
```

Thank you!

Comment: `I would like to manually trigger the function and wait a reasonable time. But, I would also like to deactivate the timerTrigger`So you want to disable the timerTrigger and you still want it act as a timertrigger function?

Comment: If you want to test you could set up a http trigger function to manually invoke it then change it to TimerTrigger.

Comment: @GeorgeChen The wording was not clear. What I mean is that I want to disable the timerTrigger and run it on demand. ( I edit the question )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behind the scenes the way you disable is, as you've shown, with an app setting.  There is a direct REST API that lets you update or add app settings so as long as you have auth (something like MSI could provide this) to the function app you could update it from there.

That said for the scenario above I wonder if Azure Durable Functions may be a better fit.  After a change happens in the database it would kick off an instance of a durable function that would keep checking event hubs.  Or manually invoke.  That way you aren't trying to use a standard timer that will keep pinging.  [I did a similar-ish pattern a few months ago to give you an idea](https://medium.com/hackernoon/serverless-and-bitcoin-creating-price-watchers-dynamically-beea36ef194e). Not sure if that will work.

Comment: It's interesting, but in my case,  there is a lot of change that will happen in the database and the function does a lot of work. So that's why it's  call on a schedule, We don't want the function to be call every time. But I will use the rest api to update the app settings.